# How to configure .screenrc to bind backspace to ctrl-h?

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm working with a device console that maps <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to delete a character, but would like to preserve my normal workflow of using the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Is there a configuration I can add to my `~/.screenrc` configuration file to accomplish this?

http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_13.html

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#index-Backspace

This does not work

```
bind Del stuff ^H
```

This correctly converts a typed `foo` to a `barfoo`

```
bindkey -t foo stuff barfoo
```

This correctly deletes a character.

```
bindkey -t foo stuff ^H
```

But I'm unable to find the syntax for what represents the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to provide the octal code for delete:

```
bindkey "\177" stuff ^H
```